# Ninject + Windows Forms Application (C#, VS 2010)

Tags: c#, winforms, ninject

I'm trying to use Ninject with my Windows Application (C#, VS 2010).
I get an error when I build the application:

The referenced assembly "Ninject" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client".

I have tried to add System.Web to the References but I got more other errors.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project + Properties, Application tab.  Change Target Framework from "Client Profile" to the full version.  System.Web is not included in the client profile.  A very boring problem, considering that the client profile is only 15% smaller than the full install for .NET 4.0